# Use null propagation in if/else

Tags: .net

[image]

What does this resharper suggestion mean by this?
I want to return null if grid is null.
The variable "grid" is a IWebElement type from Selenium framework

Comment: ReSharper has a high false positive rate.  This is a case where it *thinks* that `?.` would be helpful, but (from what I can see) this is a bad suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means to do something like this:

```
return grid?.Whatever;
```

The `?.` returns null if grid is null, or it references Whatever if it's not null.

I would ignore the suggestion if you are writing code that other people have to maintain. Just my opinion, but it makes the code too easy to mis-read.

Comment: Note that in the OP's image, there is further code below the questioned line. This suggestion return inconditionally.

Comment: So if I want to check if variable grid is null, just using the == operator is okay?

Comment: Yes, what you have (that is visible anyway) is totally fine.